# Shell script output to Console and Log on same line?

Tags: shell, unix, solaris

Is it possible for me to cut these two lines of shell script into one line.

My two lines of code echo the same string but one goes into the Console and the other into a log file.

```
echo "Starting scriptr" `date '+%T'`  >> script.log 
echo "Starting script" `date '+%T'`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `tee`:

```
echo "Starting scriptr" `date '+%T'` | tee script.log
```

In order to append to the log file, say *tee -a*

---

Quoting from `man tee`:

```
   tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files
```

Comment: `tee -a` for appending, since the original script uses `>>`

Comment: Thanks for this! Also, if you double click the .log file it will open in Console.